# get clicked button id from a list using jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

hi my system consist of a spring maven project 
it contains a list of parents and it is showed in html page using thymeleaf template engine via **th:each** 
the problem is it work on the first button only it does not working rest of the button 
i tried below code

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $("#button").attr("name").click(function(){
                  alert($(this).attr("name"));

              });
            });
```

**Table with thymeleaf iterator**

```
<table class="table">

            <tr>
                <th>Parent Name</th>
                <!-- <th>Country</th> -->
                <!-- <th>State</th>
                        <th>District</th> -->

                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone No</th>
                <th>Email</th>

                <th>Active/Inactive</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each=" parent : ${parentList}">
                <td th:text="${parent.parentName}"></td>
                <!-- <td  th:text="${parent.district.state.country.countryName}"></td> -->
                <!--    <td  th:text="${parent.district.state.stateName}"></td>
                            <td  th:text="${parent.district.districtName}"></td> -->
                <td th:text="${parent.parentAddress}"></td>
                <td th:text="${parent.parentPhone}"></td>
                <td th:text="${parent.parentEmail}"></td>


                <td><a id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-small"
                    th:value="${parent.id}" th:name="${parent.id}" th:text="${parent.id}"></a></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
```

Comment: the id is unique for each button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First of all you are using an #ID for your button, this should be a class e.g. .button.

Second, the attr between the selector and the click is a bit weird. Try the following code

```
  $(".button").click(function(){
       alert($(this).attr("name"));
  });
```

jQuery iterates implicitly over matched elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to append response to href text..
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".button").click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("name"));
    
     $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     dataType : 'json',
     url : '/learnware/ParentChangeStatus.html',
     data : ({
      id : $(this).attr("name");
     }),
     success : function(responseData) {
      if (responseData != null) {
       
        $(this).html(responseData);
      } 
     
     }

    });
     
     });
   });

Comment: this did the trick for me I had to create empty css class with specific name for this button tho xD kinda like a hack but it works...

Answer (score 0):

$("#button").attr("name")

Gives u only the name of attr, try to get following reference

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/