# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token spring boot

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I have spring boot web app and I'm trying to add really simple `javascript` script to my `index.html` that redirects to another html on button click.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" href="../css/bootstrap.css"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" href="../css/style.css"/>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 th:inline="text">My Custom CMS Dashboard</h1>

            <a href="/addNewPost"><button class="btn btn-primary block"> Add new Post </button></a>

            <table class="table posts">
                <tr th:each="post : ${posts}" class="post">
                    <td th:text="${post.title}" class="title"></td>
                    <td th:text="${post.text}" class="text"></td>
                    <td th:text="${post.user.username}" class="username"></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn block" id="editPostButton" onClick="redirectToEditPost()"> Edit Post </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="postId" th:text="${post.id}" type="hidden" style="display:none"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js/}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/editPost.js}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my javascript file: editPost.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function redirectToEditPost(){
        window.location = '/editPost/' + $('input#postId').val();
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError`: Invalid or unexpected token

I'm pretty sure that it's some weird bug (*coughs* JavaScript *coughs*) and not actual syntax error since I saw similar posts that had weird issues like cashing of index.html or something like that.

Can anyone help me figure this out since I'm not really in good terms with JavaScript errors or debugging JavaScript or anything related to JavaScript

I'm aware that this might be something dealing with Spring Boot configuration or something other than JavaScript so I'm leaving `spring-mvc` tags...

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missing `);` after your script code like below:-

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function redirectToEditPost(){
        window.location = '/editPost/' + $('input#postId').val();
    }
});
```

Comment: hi I think that was the issue lol, that error doesn't show up anymore, but my code doesn't do what I wanted it to do but that's another problem...

Answer (score 1):

Adding an event handler directly to a button is not best practice.

Leave the button as is:

```
<button class="btn block" id="editPostButton"> Edit Post </button>
```

Your document ready could then add the event handler to the button like so since you are already using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editPostButton').on('click', function () {
                window.location = '/editPost/' + $('input#postId').val();
        });
});
```

Comment: hmm, thanks but another problem is that the postId input value doesn't get fetched  :/

Comment: Can you check your DOM if there is a "value" attribute on your hidden input? also "style="display:none"" is not really necessary, maybe that's another issue.

Comment: sry but I know that display:none isn't necessary but for some reason that field is shown on the html even though I put type as hidden... and value attribute is empty, I think that thymeleaf put the actual value inside the <td> tags for some reason

Comment: Try th:value= instead of th:text=

Comment: wow thanks Alen, th:value filled the value attribute of input element now this little script works like intended, thanks a lot! I'm a thymeleaf newbie as well.

Comment: No problem, never used thymeleaf but did some googling :)

Comment: only thing is that now the script is run at the beginning when I load the site and the onClick function only triggers for the first button but not for the rest of them generated by thymeleaf even though they have the same id when the html is rendered in the browser... hmm is there better way to implement onClick event

Comment: Since you are repeating your rows, you are creating duplicate ids for your button and inputs which is not valid html. You could remove the hidden input completely, add a `th:attr="data-post-id=${post.id}"` attribute to your button and then change $('input#postId').val() to $(this).attr('data-post-id')

Comment: yes the issue seems to be in editPostButton id only the first button is being triggered even with placing the post id as attribute on button as you suggested

Comment: thanks Alen I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311511/get-clicked-button-id-from-a-list-using-jquery I fetched the button elements via css class editPostButton kinda hacked it but it works